# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) favicon.ico

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Node.JS site through Heroku and I keep getting this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) favicon.ico" I searched around and thought I would add the following to my header

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
```

However I am still getting this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This specific problem is why packages like [`express-favicion`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-favicon) and [`serve-favicon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon) exist. They add a handler for the `favicon.ico` file.

What you've done there has only made things worse as it tells the client that the icon for the page is actually the page itself.

Comment: Does Heroku require that I have a favicon? This is my first time trying to deploy so I am unsure. If so, do I need to use an express favicon middleware?

Comment: Heroku doesn't care, but your browser does, and it will relentlessly hound the server until it gets an icon. The reason you're getting an error is because your application is not expecting a request to `/favicon.ico` and is freaking out.

Comment: How would you recommend I fix it then?

Comment: Use one of those libraries, or some other of your choosing, and create a `favicon.ico` file where they say to put one. If you don't have an ICO converter, there are bunches of them [online](http://www.png2ico.com).

Comment: It keeps directing me to "http://my-heroku-app-1000.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico" Do I need to create a separate file in the root directory then?

Comment: You need to tell the Express plugin where to find your icon, so be sure you've configured that path properly. Test it on your local dev machine first before deploying to be sure it serves it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this issue was seen due to the failure of the backend services. Restarting the backend services/server resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had the same problem, after I checked it turned out that the VPN in my browser was still on, after I turned it off the problem was gone