# Why I get 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)'?

Tags: iis, favicon, http-status-code-503

I have a problem with a server-client project. The server is a ASP MVC project, and the client is an Angular project. When I deploy my server project through IIS and browse it, I get this:
[image]
I have installed on my angular project the packages Tadman suggested on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362439/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-503-service-unav) but unsuccessfully. I have tried to use old published versions of my site but the result is the same. My client project contains the `favicon.ico` file in its src folder.
How could I solve it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code See if your web app keeps crashing and forces IIS to disable the application pool.

Comment: @LexLi, it's strange that if I use localhost instead of IP, it works. Why I get this error only when using external IP?

Comment: If you have multiple sites (and different site bindings), then requests on localhost and IP can go to different sites and come back with different responses, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone encounters this error, I managed to get rid of the it by creating a new site in IIS with the same publish source as the old one.